# how do I get the color that surrounds the Contour from outside, and how to fill the inside of a contour with a color?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I wrote a program that takes a picture as an input and detects the written text
I need to edit my program to add two more functionalities

First
since I already was able to get the Contour coordinates(done), I want to know how do I get the color of the background that surrounds the contour line of each character ( at multiple points because I want to calculate the average of RGB color values surrounding that character )
I just don't know if there is already a function to do what I want to do or if there is a specific approach that I should follow

second,
I tried to fill the inside of the Contour but it did not work, can someone help me to know why
I did try both thickness=-1 and thickness=cv2.FILLE in my cv2.drawContours, nothing worked, clearly only the control line is blue but what is inside is not blue

I know that the code is not perfect and there are so many comments but it is because I'm Kim trying new stuff
thank you in advance to everyone who's going to help

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui
def Contour(img):
    Contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in Contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        # print(area)
        # if area<150: could be useded to be cpecific
        # we need a copy of the image so we dont draw on the original or thickness=-1
        cv2.drawContours(imgcpy, cnt, -1, (255,0,0), thickness=-1)

#pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd= 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
cap= cv2
img = cv2.imread('D:\\opencv\\R\\img\\lec\\3.png')
imgcpy = img.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# for japanese txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray, lang='jpn')
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray)

imgblur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7, 7), 0)
imgcanny = cv2.Canny(img, 200, 200)
#imgDialation = cv2.dilate(imgcanny, kernel, iterations=1)
#imgeroded = cv2.erode(imgDialation, kernel, iterations=1)
imBlank = np.zeros_like(img)
# waste of time only the same picture work -_-
# imstack = np.hstack((gray,gray,gray))
Contour(imgcanny)
cv2.imshow('Contour', imgcpy)



#img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(txt)

print(Contour(imgcanny))
#cv2.imshow('test', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "first" issue is solved by

1. getting a mask, either

   - using `connectedComponents` or
   - by filling a mask using `drawContours` into `np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)`
2. `dilate` the mask, then
3. subtract the mask from the dilated version (literal subtraction will work, but so do bitwise operations)

The result is a mask that contains pixels just *outside* of the contour.

Use this mask to get those pixel values:

```py
# have `mask` somehow, which should be dtype uint8

dilated = cv.dilate(mask)
surrounding = dilated - mask

values = img[surrounding != 0] # numpy indexing using a boolean array
meancolor = values.mean(axis=(0,1)) # sum/average over both axes
```

The "second" issue is that you pass a single contour to `drawContours`, which expects a **list of contours**.

Change your code to pass `[cnt]` instead of just `cnt`:

```py
cv2.drawContours(imgcpy, [cnt], -1, (255,0,0), thickness=-1)
```

If you only pass `cnt`, it will interpret the list of *points* (a contour is a list of points) as a list of *contours*, hence it will interpret each point as a contour... and that's just a point, not a contour.

Comment: sorry for the late replay, thank you so much for the help, I will try the solution today after my part-time is over

Comment: I just found a bug in my answer. it is corrected now. the lookup needs to use the `surrounding` mask, not `mask` mask